# FBOs are not working properly in OSX

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl, fbo

I had this problem for some time, and I couldn't find a solution.

Here I initialize the Framebuffer:

```
//Initialize buffers
    glGenBuffers(1, &primaryBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, primaryBuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, Statics::ScreenWidth, Statics::ScreenHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

    glGenTextures(1, &colorTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTexture);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8,  Statics::ScreenWidth, Statics::ScreenHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glGenTextures(1, &depthTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32,  Statics::ScreenWidth, Statics::ScreenHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTexture, 0);

    int res = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (res == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        printf("GOOD!\n");
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

I use it in the render function this way:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, primaryBuffer);
glViewport(0, 0, Statics::ScreenWidth, Statics::ScreenHeight);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

SetCamera();
DrawScene1();

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

glViewport(0, 0, Statics::ScreenWidth, Statics::ScreenHeight);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
SetCamera();
DrawScene2();
```

What supposed to happen here is that "scene1" is rendered in the attached Framebuffer texture.  And "scene2" should show up in the screen.
"scene2" does show up in the screen, but when I use the rendered Framebuffer texture, this is what appears:
[image: Looks like some GPU memory garbage! :)]

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What is the point of `depthTexture` if you're using a renderbuffer instead of a texture for your depth buffer?

Comment: You didn't say what exactly the problem was. What should the result look like? Is the problem the squares in the texture? Oh, and don't use `GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP` with FBOs; there's a reason why the FBO extension introduced the `glGenerateMipmaps` function.

Comment: The output is supposed to be a door inside a door.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  It displays this garbage texture again.

Comment: This is too much of a debugging problem to answer without full access to the source code and data. The only thing I can suggest is to reduce the complexity of everything (draw simpler stuff, etc) until you have it boiled down to the basics: draw something to texture, render something else with that texture. Then, when that works, start adding the pieces back step-by-step.

Comment: Can you please post an image with intended result (use some image editing program for this).

Answer (score 2):

From what you wrote I have understood that DrawScene2() should render the entire scene, while DrawScene1() should render into a part of what DrawScene2() has produced.

Since you haven't given away any details (or the entire code) of DrawScene2(), I can only make an educated guess here: The problem will be DrawScene2 (). Since you are using the result of DrawScene1() as render source here, you probably just slapped the entire FBO on the render target, instead of treating it as a regular texture, i.e. setting up the proper world and texture coordinates for it before it gets rendered (i.e. the boundaries of the door rendered by DrawScene2() that you want to "paint" with what DrawScene1() has produced).